# If ctx.message.mentions != None always returns true with Discord.py Custom Bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm working on a custom Discord bot, and I'm currently trying to make a /spam (message) (amount) command as my first full Discord.py project, but I'm currently running into a problem where when I check if the (message) parameter contains an @ mention with this code:

```
@bot.command()
async def spam(ctx, arg, amount=None):

    # If message contains @ mention send error message.
    if ctx.message.mentions != None:             # <-- Error here
        await ctx.channel.send("**Whoops!** Sorry, you can't say roles in spam messages.")
        print(f"{ctx.message.author} attempted to spam a spam-sensitive word.")
        return
```

But it doesn't give me an error message, it just tells me:
"Whoops! Sorry, you can't say roles in spam messages." in Discord.

Also, I am aware that when I remove the "return" line it continues the script and does the /spam anyway, but when I do that it sends the error message first and then does the spam, which isn't exactly what I'm aiming for.

I tried a lot of different variations of this code, but each time it achieved the same result of either thinking there was an @mention every time the command was called, or thinking there was never an @mention ever.

I also tried using a list and checking over the list to see if it contained anything in the list, but that doesn't work exactly the same as what I'm trying to get to work, so I'm not going to do that I don't think.

Any help would be great! :D

Comment: `return` should halt the processing of the command and not send the spam messages. Can you provide more code of the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [`ctx.message.mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.mentions) is always a list (empty list when there are no mentions) so you should replace your mentions check with this:

```py
if ctx.message.mentions != []:
    ...
```

or

```py
if len(ctx.message.mentions) != 0:
    ...
```

Any of these two would work

Comment: Thank you so much!
Sorry, that's actually so simple, I probably would've know that. xD
It's working perfectly now. Thank you!